# ¿Cómo puedo acceder desde el Mac a la aplicación ASP.NET de mi maquina virtual en Parallels?

Tags: asp.net, windows, visual-studio, iis

Soy desarrollador `.NET` así que por razones obvias necesito usar `Windows` para trabajar, entonces lo que hice fue crear una maquina virtual con `Windows 10` en mi `Mac`, ahora lo que quiero es acceder a la aplicación `ASP.NET` de windows pero desde el `Mac`.

Ya comprobé varios tutoriales para solucionar este problema pero lo que ocurre ahora es que, al colocar la `IP` de mi maquina virtual en el navegador del `Mac` solo me sale la pagina de inicio del `IIS` algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al colocar la `IP` de mi maquina virtual mas el nombre de mi sitio web, por ejemplo `http://10.211.55.1/sitioweb`, me sale un `error 404`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que pido es que si alguien sabe de algo que no haya realizado para que esto funcione correctamente.

Comment: con que soft creaste la virtual ? validaste que el firewall de windows no este bloqueando el acceso a ese puerto, en este caso el puerto 80 ? Si accedes a stio web desde dentro de la virtual de win10 usando "http://localhost/sitioweb" resuelve correctamente, puedes ver la pagina en el browser?

Comment: `sitioweb` está creado como *Aplicación* dentro del *sitio* **Default Web Site**?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini lo cree con parallels con respecto al firewall lo deshabilite. cuando pongo `localhost/misitioweb` no entra, pero si pongo en nombre que le puse al agregar el host si funciona.

Comment: pones localhost desde donde? estas dentro de Win10 o desde Mac. El localhost solo funcionara desde dentro de Win10.  Ese host que mencionas es el nombre de la virtual Win10 ? seria raro que Mac resuelva por nombre y no por ip

Comment: @LeandroTuttini pongo local host desde wind 10 pero no funciona, cuando digo nombre del host me refiero al nombre que se asigna al crear nuevo sitio web en el servidor `iis` cuando le colocas el nombre también le colocas el puerto que quieres que use.

Comment: El nombre que le pongas al sitio en el IIS no aplica en la url, solo importa el puerto si es que lo defines en uno diferente al "Default Web Site" (el cual usa el puerto 80). El sitio desde dentro de Win10 lo accedes con localhost o 127.0.0.1, por eso es http://localhost:{puerto}/, pero esto si creas un sitio nuevo y no un virtual directory

Answer (score 2):

Creo que no es un problema de la virtualización ni de la configuración del firewall porque estás accediendo a la página de inicio de ´IIS´

Creo que simplemente te falta configurar el proyecto para que se ejecute con `IIS`, abre las propiedades del proyecto, ve a la pestaña web y asegúrate que tienes seleccionado **IIS local**.

Si no es así, seleccionarlo y al guardar se creará la aplicación en `IIS` apuntando a la carpeta de tu proyecto. Si ya lo tienes, pulsa en el botón **Crear directorio virtual**

[image: COnfiguración proyecto ASp.NET en IIS]

Comment: Hola @José-Gregorio-Calderón ¿se solucionó tu problema? ¿fue eso lo que pasaba?